# Search for specific job listings with a given technology returns fewer results than search for companies using that tech?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I've been searching recently for PHP jobs
So, I went to /jobs, and searched for `php`, all I got is like.. around... 10 jobs with the remote flag set, or around 30 if the remote flag is unset

However, if I go the `Search companies` tab, and search for PHP, I get hundreds of companies with jobs with `php` tag attached

So why searching for companies bring results more than normal job search?

Comment: It could easily be the case that there are more companies that use PHP than are actively hiring for PHP.

Comment: How is this a bug? Searching for jobs with the text '_php_' is different than using the tag.....

Comment: I believe searching companies will also be searching for companies that use php in general, it may be that the jobs they're hiring for aren't php roles - [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/genesis-groupe)

Comment: Ah, now that makes more sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a bug.

When you search on the "search companies" tab, you are searching against the tags a company has defined in their tech stack.

When you search via the "search jobs" tab, you are searching against what a job specification has defined as technologies used within that particular role.

Since a companies tech stack is quite likely to encompass more than what a particular role will include, you will find more results.